# Can we compute bivariate from marginal distributions?

Tags: distributions, multivariate-analysis, marginal-distribution

Can we do that? If yes, then what are the conditions which should be met?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just knowing the marginal distributions of two variables isn't sufficient to specify their bivariate distribution. You need more information about their joint relationship. Simple example: two random normals can have any particular correlation with each other, but still have the same marginal distributions.

It sounds like you may want to consider [copulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula).

Comment: @Hong, and how are copulas supposed to help if you only have the marginal distributions?

Comment: @cardinal, the point is that copulas are a way of specifying the additional information you need to obtain the bivariate distribution, if you already have the marginals.

Comment: @Harpreet If you make it to section 3 of @Hong's Wikipedia reference you will see that Sklar's Theorem answers your question affirmatively (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_%28statistics%29#Sklar.27s_theorem ).

Comment: @Hong, That's fine, I know what a copula is. My point is that they don't help here. If all you have is the marginal distributions and, not, say, the $(X,Y)$ pairs, all a copula will do is let you make up whatever dependence you'd like. They have no utility in terms of inference because you have no information about the joint distribution.

Comment: @Harpreet, even if the marginals are normal, the joint distribution can be non-normal. You can use copulas, but as @cardinal said, you need additional information.